# Will a PC's passive ability function while they are polymorphed?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, polymorph

Let's say a Gnome bard polymorphs themselves into a triceratops, then has to make a strength check to bust through a door frame. Would they be able to add jack of all trades to said check? As it is a passive ability?